# How to use dataimporter.EntityName.last_index_time in delta import?

Tags: solr

Right now, we have a dataimport.properties file per core, with each core's delta import using the `${dataimporter.last_index_time}` value for its delta import.

However, the import also writes a `EntityName.last_index_time` to the properties file.

data-config.xml:

```
...
<document>
    <entity
        name="EntityName"
        ...
    </entity>
</document>
```

.properties file:

```
#Mon Dec 23 11:41:18 CET 2013
last_index_time=2013-12-23 11\:41\:17
EntityName.last_index_time=2013-12-23 11\:41\:17
```

I am unable to use `${dataimporter.EntityName.last_index_time}`, is there some other way to use that specific `last_index_time`?

Comment: Either `${dih.EntityName.last_index_time}` or `${dataimporter.EntityName.last_index_time}` should work fine. Any reason why you're unable to use `${dataimporter.EntityName.last_index_time}` ??

Comment: I'm unable to use it, because it doesn't work 8) I've tried, but the delta import always does a full import when I try using ${dataimporter.EntityName.last_index_time}

Comment: Can you post a snippist of your data-config.xml?

Comment: Took me a while, but finally got some sensible search results. I discovered that this is a known bug: SOLR-4788